# Mouse scrolling weird/unresponsive in virtual box

Tags: virtualbox, mouse, mouse-scroll

I'm using virtual box 5.0.14 and I've installing guest additions and the extension pack. I am able to scroll up/down however frequently as I'm scrolling down it scrolls up instead. If I disable mouse integration the problem stops however the mouse pointer does not feel very smooth compared to using mouse integration. Any idea what the problem could be?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
It seems it is a Virtual Box.
I found [this Virtual Box forum post](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=68702):

> Fixed this issue, I ejected the guest.iso and inserted it again and it resolved the mouse scrolling issue.

I followed the suggested decision and it helped.
So eject guest additions, insert again and reinstall.